# How can I run an alert program when a Windows Service fails to start?

Tags: windows, windows-services, windows-server-2012

I have a Windows service whose start-up is set to 'Automatic', so it starts whenever the system boots up.

But this jobs sometimes did not start due to unknown reasons. I want to setup an alert program (.bat) to run whenever the service fails to start.

I tried using Recovery Mode options in service property, but it is not working. I think it is for jobs crashing with errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a script that lists the service of yours and see whether it is running (using the [sc](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb490995.aspx) command). Then you might to put that script to Startup menu. Should the script run before the service is started, you would need to schedule the script to be running periodically (to give the service some time to be started) using either of [schtasks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/bb736357(v=vs.85).aspx), [at](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/313565), or back in the nt4 days there was (still functional I presume) nice gui version of `at` in nt 4 resource kit called [winat](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/158388), if you have access to it.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. But is it possible to use Recovery Option in my case ?

Comment: It might, if it ever worked fine. But this forum is not the best one for asking about the Recovery Option, I'd suggest [Super User](http://superuser.com), or maybe better [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com)